# Adding an achor with a url, while passing a url as a property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass a url to href through a property.

I am trying to pass the {props.github} to href. But it isn't working.

I created a property object with a property called github. Like below.

```
export const projectList = [
{   title: 'Title',
    github: 'https://github.com/',
    summary: 'Summary.'
},
{   title: 'Title',
    github: 'https://github.com/',
    summary: 'Summary.'
}];

export default Project;
```

This is how I am trying to do this but when I click GitHub, no page opens.

The github text is not clickable and doesn't redirect me to the github page.[image]

I would like this text to be clickable and redirect me to the github link.

Below is how I created a Project Element.

```
const Project = (props) => {
    return(
         <div className='bg-navy ba bw1 b--dark-blue dib pa4 ma1 br3 grow shadow-5'> 
            <img className='b' alt='Photo' src='' />
            <div>
                <h2 className='light-blue '>{props.title}</h2>
                <p className='washed-blue'>{props.summary}</p>
                <a href={props.github} >GitHub</a> ////// THIS LINE
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

All other props.x work correctly.

This is How I passed the projectList into the Project Element.

```
import React from 'react';
import Project from './Project.js'

const CardList = ({projectList}) => {
    const cardDraw = projectList.map((proj, i) => {
        return <Project key={i} title={projectList[i].title} title={projectList[i].github} summary={projectList[i].summary}/>
    })
    return (
        <div>
            {cardDraw}

        </div>
    );
}

export default CardList;
```

Comment: Can you share the entire component that the anchor tag is implemented in? How are you passing the `projectList` object as prop down to your component?

Comment: Please make it part of your question above by editing it.

Comment: How do you pass the props to the `<Project/>` component? That is missing in your examples.

Comment: The anchor tag in your edited example also does not correspond to your previous example above.

Comment: Yeah I slightly edited the code to make it simpler but I guess it didn't work :(

Comment: Is `projectList` what you think it is? You image also doesn't show the summary etc.

Comment: You can remove and change what you wrote previously, no need to keep things that make your question inconsistent, you don't have to make "edit 1" "edit 2", just change things you have there already :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the property name `link` in the parent and the property name `github` in the child

Comment: @AaronEtheridge Please don't edit your question to contain the solution from this answer! If you do that then the answer no longer seems relevant.